# How to find a html tag by class in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I am working on a simple dictionary and can't figure out the way to  print a specific html tag in this example span with the class of "ind".

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("Please enter your word:")
word = input("")

url = "https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/" + str(word)
print(url)

info = ""

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for span in soup.find_all('spanclass: ind}'):
  print(span.text)
  info += span.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
span_tags = soup.find_all('span', class_="ind")

for span in span_tags:
    print(span.text)
```

Comment: Easy fix, I thought I've tried this before but apparently not in the right way. Thank You! I'll mark it as my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @RobinDieu happens all the time, you may be able to accept the answer by now. cheers!